# Displaying jsGrid nested object array

Tags: arrays, object, nested, jsgrid

Using `jsGrid` I am attempting to display information from my server. The format that I receive the data is thus:

```
{
  "Response": [
    {
      "this": "1",
      "that": 42,
      "theOtherThing": "2016-01-28T19:45:19.093Z"
    },
    {
      "this": "2",
      "that": 49,
      "theOtherThing": "2016-01-28T19:45:19.093Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I pull this information out of the object **Response** so that I can display it in my `jsGrid` fields?

```
fields: [
            {name: 'this', type: 'text', width: 100},
            {name: 'that', type: 'number', width: 100},
            {name: 'theOtherThing', type: 'text', width: 100}
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

So I just needed to alter the format of my ajax call:

```
controller: {
    loadData: function () {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ThisGoesSomewhere',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res){
                deferred.resolve(res.Response);
            },
            error: function(res){
                console.log('error ' + res);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }
}
```